# Child a tag not taking the table-cell parent height

Tags: html, css

I arranged the main menu navigation using table property. Having anchor tag inside the li tag. And provided drop-down arrow for anchor tag using "after" method. Now I am facing an issue that my anchor tag **not taking** its parent **li full height** which has display: table-cell. And I can't set position absolute to my anchor as I already set position: relative to display arrow in its after.
The reason I need my anchor tag to get full height is. My menu may have two lines like 1. XXxxxxxxxx xxxxx 2.xxxxxx so the first link will come two line as no enough width. and second one will come in single line.

```
ul.tb-megamenu-nav.nav{
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   table-layout: fixed;
   position: relative;
}

.tb-megamenu .nav > li.level-1 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    min-height: 48px;
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    min-width: 16.56686626746507%;
    position: static;
    list-style: none;
}

.tb-megamenu .nav > li > a {
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 8px 7%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
 }

.tb-megamenu .tb-megamenu-nav > li.dropdown > a:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -14px;
    border-top: 14px solid #0092d0;
    border-left: 14px solid transparent;
    border-right: 14px solid transparent;
    z-index: 999999;
```

}

Comment: can you create a snippet including the html?

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}
ul.tb-megamenu-nav.nav {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  position: relative;
}
.tb-megamenu .nav > li.level-1 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 48px;
  float: none;
  display: table-cell;
  min-width: 16.56686626746507%;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
.tb-megamenu .nav > li > a {
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 8px 7%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
.tb-megamenu .tb-megamenu-nav > li.dropdown > a:after {
  content: "➤";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -14px;
  border-top: 14px solid #0092d0;
  border-left: 14px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid transparent;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tb-megamenu-nav nav">
  <li class="level-1"></li>
  <li class="dropdown">

    <a href='#'></a>

  </li>
```

Comment: Thanks @zer00ne.. but I updated my question plc check and help me out

Comment: I think we need some HTML, I tried to guess  as to what it looks like, but a close guess only counts in horseshoes and grenades...